# Распространение приложений в AppStore

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, мобильная-разработка, распространение

Публиковали приложения через ItunnesConnect от профиля разработчика (Организация в форме ИП, платим 99$ в год). При публикации очередного приложения, Эппл отклоняет и пишет следующее:

> Guideline 5.2.1 - Legal - Intellectual Property
>
> The seller and company names associated with your app do not reflect
>   the name "Федеральная служба СП по РО” in the app or its metadata, as
>   required by Guideline 5.2.1 of the App Store Review Guidelines.
>
> Next Steps
>
> Your app must be published under a seller name and company name that
>   reflects the Федеральная служба СП по РО name. If you have developed
>   this app on behalf of a client, please advise your client to add you
>   to the development team of their Apple Developer account. If your
>   client does not yet have an Apple Developer account, they can enroll
>   in the Apple Developer Program through the Apple Developer website.
>
> To request an update to the company name or entity type associated
>   with this Apple Developer Program account, the Team Agent will need to
>   edit the account information. On the Apple Developer website, go to
>   Account, then select Membership. On the Membership page, click "Need
>   to edit this information?" to submit your requested changes.
>
> This app must be submitted under the content owner’s own Apple
>   Developer account.
>
> To request a fee waiver for nonprofit organizations, accredited
>   educational institutions, or U.S.-based government entities, follow
>   the steps outlined on the Apple Developer Program Membership Fee
>   Waivers page.

Ранее были такие случаи, мы им кидали договор на передачу ПО организации под которую писали приложение и тогда они пропускали без проблем, здесь же уперлись и всё.
Может кто сталкивался, как решали?
Выход только покупка Enterprise и распространение через In-house ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

имхо, лучше заморочиться и под клиента оформить аккаунт, а вы будете управлять им и публиковать приложение/обновления. Enterprise не выход для этих целей, можете попасть под блокировку своего аккаунта.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Больше всего даже волнует то, что проект массовый (типовое решение), мы предлагаем для организаций. И получается, что можем сталкиваться при публикации с каждым случаем на иос, и регить каждую организацию (+99$) тоже как -то..

Comment: Это обычное дело при тиражировании. Как вариант, закладывать в затраты.

Comment: Да и народ жаловался, что сейчас Enterprise-аккаунт практически не возможно получить.

Answer (score 1):

Несколько раз с таким приходилось сталкиваться, на стадии первой публикации приложения. Отправляли договора, по всему приложению расставляли "Developed by ..." - бесполезно.
Помогали клиентам оформить аккаунт и уже под этими аккаунтами публиковали приложение.
Так что, как уже ответили выше, легче создать аккаунт клиенту.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ!