# Apple отклонила приложение для iOS

Tags: ios, apple

Публикуем приложение и на проверке приходит следующий ответ от Apple:

> Your app must be published under a seller name and company name that
> reflects the <здесь имя компании-клиента> name. If you have developed
> this app on behalf of a client, please advise your client to add you
> to the development team of their Apple Developer account. If your
> client does not yet have an Apple Developer account, they can enroll
> in the Apple Developer Program through the Apple Developer website.

Мы хотим опубликовать приложение, чтобы разработчиком числилась наша компания, а не компания клиента. Само собой, клиент не против. Как сказано выше, мы добавили нашу девовскую учетку в их команду, однако приходит тот же ответ (походу бот или типа того). Может кто-то уже имел с этим дело? Хотелось бы все-таки опубликовать приложение от имени нашего разработчика.

Comment: Напишите в поддержку на портале App Store Connect.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Распространение приложений в AppStore](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1090676/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b2-appstore)

Comment: Удалось победить? В чем суть приложения?